# When exporting from Kartik ExportMenu widget to Excel, lines breaks only show when double click on it

Tags: php, excel, yii2

I installed yii2 extension Kartik ExportMenu since I need to export the filtered result of a GridView to MS Excel 2007. One column of the grid contains a related model, separated each related record by line breaks. The problem is that in the generated Excel file, the content shows in one line and the line breaks only appears when double click each cell. I need line breaks to appear all automatically.

I'm not sure if it's a problem about code or Excel configuration. I've tried in Excel for Mac and in Excel for Windows, with same result.
This is the code of that grid column:

```
[
            'label' => 'Pagos',
            'value' => function($model) {
                $result = '';
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($model->ingresos as $ingreso) {
                    if (++$i === count($model->ingresos)) {
                        $result = $result . $ingreso->fecha . " - " . $ingreso->moneda->simbolo . " " .
                        $ingreso->monto . " - " . $ingreso->formaPago->name;
                    } else {
                        $result = $result . $ingreso->fecha . " - " . $ingreso->moneda->simbolo . " " .
                        $ingreso->monto . " - " . $ingreso->formaPago->name . "\n";
                    }
                }
                if ($result != '')
                    return $result;
                else
                    return '-';
            },
            'format' => 'html',
        ],
```

I also have tried the line breaks with `<br>` and `\r`, with same result, it opens in one line and I have to double click each cell in order to see the line breaks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think if you use the `<br />` tag and set the option [`"stripHtml"=>false`](http://demos.krajee.com/export#option-stripHtml) it should show you correctly as the default value for `autoWidth` is `true` for the column

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I've tried that ("stripHtml"=>false) and it didn't work. Not just shows also the content in one line, but also I got html tags in the document.

Comment: @GastonBerenstein were you able to solve it?

Comment: @temirbek nope. I found that what I have to do is to wrap the text. If I do that manually in MS Excel, it works, if I do it programatically, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Of course now it's not relevant for you, but maybe it will be useful for others. It seems `\n` is good as separator, nor stripHtml nor format =html options isn't required. It seems the user must choose "Wrap text" option in excel to show the column as required.

Maybe `br` html tag is also good separator, when Excel break lines if you double click on the cell. User must choose "Wrap text" option on this column too. Maybe someone know the option in kartik module to avoid the user additional interaction...Sorry for my English.